# How to Execute Update SQL Script in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have this code to execute a stored procedure (Update SP) in ASP.Net, unfortunately record is not updating when I run the code.

This is my code:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = Connt.GetConnection(TblName))
{
        sqlConnection.Open();
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlScript, sqlConnection))
        {
            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddRange(SqlParam);
        }
}
```

Where `SqlScript` is the variable for the stored procedure name and `SqlParam` is the parameters.

Please help me figure out what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Your main issue is that you have an UPDATE stored procedure and you are using the SelectCommand property of the DataAdapter. The constructor is also assigning the SqlScript to the SelectCommand.

Comment: Yes and thats the main mistake. SQLCommand should be use instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi  you can try something like this

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME;Integrated Security=True";

public void samplefunct(params object[] adparam)
   {
       sqlConnection.Open();
       sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
       sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       sqlCommand.CommandText = "SPName";

       sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = adparam[0];
       sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = adparam[1];
       sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Param3", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = adparam[2];
       sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: This works fine with just minor adjustments to my code but this code contains the functionality and logic you need. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for voting hope it helps you a lot

Comment: @Angelo : nice answer +1, i have a question here that how would you know that there are only 3 parameters in the `adparam` object array? and what happens when user only sends 2 parameters to the `samplefunct` function?

Comment: ahh you have to send the same parameter count like samplefunct(param1,param2,param3)if not it gives you error unless you put something like try catch

Comment: in short you should know how many parameters to past to that function, or you can set variables for you to easily know how many parameters to send like samplefunct(string param1, string param2, string param3)

Comment: @Angelo : yes that is ok, but as you are using `params` it allows any no of parameters , even while complining it wont let user know so i think it is good to check the count of parameters using `.Length` property before proceeding further otherwise it can cause exception when parameters are less than 3 IMO.

Comment: yah your right thanks for the advise i will use for my future codings

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("ProcedureName", conn) { 
                           CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure }) {
   conn.Open();
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   conn.Close();
}
```

With a Param:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", 123));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. How can I add parameter to the SP using your given code.